# Save multiple image profiles to SQL Server database from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, frame, filepicker

I am creating a cross platform school app. I have a page that displays the students in a class and their pictures. I added a functionality that enables the teacher to change the profile of the student or add one if none. the thing is that this functionality works great on android in which they can change or add multiple profiles for different students at once. but on ios, something seems wrong. If they add multiple pics, the pictures won't be uploaded to my database and thus no pics are displayed, but if they add only one pic for a student, it will be uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
private void generateProfiles(double width, List<studentdetailsformanagment> lstofstudents,List<absenteesIds>attending)
{
    studentprofiles.Children.Clear();
    dtAttedndance.Clear();

    double nbofcolumns = width / 180;
    double nbofrows = lstofstudents.Count / nbofcolumns;

    for (int i = 0; i < nbofcolumns-1; i++)
    {
        studentprofiles.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 170 });
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < nbofrows + 1; j++)
    {
        studentprofiles.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 170 });
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lstofstudents.Count; i++)
    {
        var student = lstofstudents[i];

        DataRow dtdr = dt.Select("[id] ='" + student.id + "'").FirstOrDefault();

        if (dtdr == null) 
            dt.Rows.Add(Preferences.Get("AcademicYearId", ""),student.id, section.Text, student.profilePic);

        SwipeItem delete = new SwipeItem
                {
                    Text = "Remove",
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
                };

        SwipeItems items = new SwipeItems
                {
                    Mode = SwipeMode.Execute
                };
        items.Add(delete);

        List<SwipeItem> swipeItems = new List<SwipeItem>() { delete };

        Image img = new Image
                {
                    Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.user_profile.png"),
                   
                    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill,
                    Margin = -20,
                    HeightRequest = 100,
                    WidthRequest = 100,
                };
                
        if (student.profilePic == null)
            img.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.user_profile.png");
        else
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(student.profilePic);
            img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
        }

        StackLayout stdinfo = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, ClassId="false" };

        if (attending.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < attending.Count; j++)
            {
                        if (student.id == attending[j].id)
                        {
                            stdinfo.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0d98ba");
                            stdinfo.ClassId = "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Label stdname = new Label { TextColor = Color.Black, Text = student.name, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
                Frame circleImageFrame = new Frame
                {
                    ClassId = student.id,
                    Margin = 10,
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    CornerRadius = 50,
                    HeightRequest = 60,
                    WidthRequest = 60,
                    IsClippedToBounds = true,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,

                    Content = img
                };
               
                stdinfo.Children.Add(circleImageFrame);
                stdinfo.Children.Add(stdname);
                
                SwipeView swipe = new SwipeView
                {
                    Threshold=70,
                    LeftItems = new SwipeItems(items),
                    Content = stdinfo,
                };
 
                AddTap.Tapped += async (s, evt) =>
                {
                    
                    try
                    {

                        await PickAndShow(null, img);
                        byte[] profilepic = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgpath);
                        string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(profilepic);
                        try
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.Select("[id] ='" + circleImageFrame.ClassId + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                            if (dr != null) dr["profilePic"] = imageBase64;


                            var obj = stdprofiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == circleImageFrame.ClassId);
                            if (obj != null) obj.profilePic = imageBase64;
                        }
                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Error", exp.Message, "ok");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception exp)
                    {
                        
                    }
                  

                };
                circleImageFrame.GestureRecognizers.Add(AddTap);
```

this is the function i use to display circular frames with profiles.

```
async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options, Image image)
        {
            imgpath = "";
            try
            {
                var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
                    if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                        result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
                    }
                }
                imgpath = result.FullPath;
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              
            }

            return null;
        }
```

and this is the function i use to pick an image from the folders in the device

this is the code that runs when i press submit:

```
   async private void submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            submit.IsEnabled = false;
            if (flagEditorAttednd == true)
            {
                flagEditorAttednd = false;
                edit.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.edit.png");
                select.IsEnabled = false;
                urlClass urldata = new urlClass();
                string uri = urldata.url + "/PostStdDetails";

                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage responsepost = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                    if (responsepost.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                    {
                        string outcome = await responsepost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(outcome);
                        await DisplayAlert("Students Distribution", "Students in section " + section.Text + " were edited successfully", "OK");
                        var width = this.Width;
                        generateProfiles(width, stdprofiles, absentstds);
                        nbofstds.Text = stdprofiles.Count.ToString() + " Students";
                        submit.IsEnabled = true;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", "Response Failed!", "Cancel");
                        submit.IsEnabled = true;

                    }
                }
                catch (System.Net.WebException exp)
                {
                    submit.IsEnabled = true;
                    bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Please Check Your Internet Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                    if (ans == true)
                        submit_Clicked(sender, e);


                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    submit.IsEnabled = true;
                    bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", exp.Message, "Retry", "Cancel");
                    if (ans == true)
                        submit_Clicked(sender, e);


                }
}
```

this is the code at the sql server side:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getstddetailsupdate]

@stdDetailsTable as StdDetailsTypeTable readonly

AS  

Begin
update  [dbo].[students]
set [section]= X.section,  [profilePic]=X.profilePic
 FROM [dbo].[students],@stdDetailsTable X where [dbo].[students].id=X.id and [dbo].[students].YearId=X.YearId
    
 end
```

this is how they appear:

[image]

when they tap on the circular frame, they can choose a pic and when they click submit, the pics chosen for each student will be uploaded. the problem is that when many pics are chosen, no pictures are uploaded. but if only one is chosen, it will be uploaded normally. why is that? i can't figure out why this is happening. thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any code that upload images to the db?

Comment: yes sorry i just added the code that runs when i click submit

Comment: have you stepped through the submit code on iOS?  Are there any errors or exceptions?  Where does the code execution diverge compared to Android?

Comment: no i don't get any errors or exceptions. the code gets executed and i get the display alert that shows that things went successfully, but when i refresh my page to see the profiles of the students, none of the pics appear

Comment: You can try to debug your code step by step, there should be some clues.

Comment: Have you debugged the server code to verify?  Do you have any logging enabled?  Don’t assume that your code is doing what you think it is doing just because you don’t get an error

Comment: i tried different things to figure out what the problem is. i tried visualizing the datatable by placing a break point but the dataset visualizer didn't appear. but the thing is that i discovered something, when 3 profile pictures are chosen, the images are saved to the database, when more than 3 are picked, none are saved. the images are saved as nvarchar(max), is it possible that there is a limit or something? like i shouldn't send more than 3 nvarchar(max) values to the sql server or something?